# Use Toolbar home button for popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

App has **Viewpager** that has ***four tab*** with ***fragment***. Second fragment has framelayout "FL" where I put fragment with listview. And when user click listview item opened new fragment with listview in this framelayout "FL" and and so on.

I am going to do ***catalog***  with prudacts with multilevel category.

**My quation:**  How can I implement that in second fragment when I opened fragment level 3 than  by clicking ***Toolbar home button*** go back to fragment level 2 and to another click back to fragment level 1  (popBackStack) and finally when click ***Toolbar home button*** go to ***first Tab***. Any help be usefull for me. Thanks

[image: catalog]

There is what I fecit:

I use home button for go ***First Tab*** from other Tabs:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.setCurrentItem(0, true);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace fragment use the below code

```
 @Override
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
            //     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }
    }
```

**Add the below mentioned code in your fragment class**

Add the below line in your Fragment onCreateView

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Use the below code to go back the previous fragment.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how can I do that from second Tab fragment in level 1 by clicking  home button go to firts Tab fragment.